# LocationServices getFusedLocationProviderClient is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-location, android-maps-v2

I want to return current user location when location is available.

this is my code:

```
fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult)
            if (locationResult.lastLocation != null && locationResult.lastLocation.latitude > 0 && locationResult.lastLocation.longitude > 0) {

                lastLocation = locationResult.lastLocation
                currentUserLatLng = LatLng(lastLocation.latitude, lastLocation.longitude)

                fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)

            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is, it's never called, I have the permission and allow my app to use gps, I set a debugger for it and it never comes in

could you help me? what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Please post full code @Navid Abutorab

Answer (score 0):

Why have you written `locationResult.lastLocation.latitude > 0` & `locationResult.lastLocation.longitude > 0` in your code? They can be negative

Answer (score 0):

Did you call requestLocationUpdates somewhere?

```
fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());
```